# Return full text element (including child/descendant elements)

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the text from the first occurrence on the page of div/p, and only the first p. The <p> contains other tags (<b>, <a href>) and the returned text from <p> stops at any other tag. Is there a way to get this line to return all the text between <p> and </p>, even between embedded tags?

```
puts doc.xpath('html/body/div/p[1]/text()').first
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
string((//div/p)[1])
```

When this XPath expression is evaluated the result is the string value of the first `p` in the document that is a child of a `div`.

By definition the **[string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)** of an element is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its text-node descendents.

Therefore, you get exactly all the text in the subtree rooted by this `p` element, with any other nodes (elements, comments, PIs) skipped.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="string(p)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (no such provided!):

```
<p>
 Hello <b>
  <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/">XML</a>
   World!</b>
</p>
```

**the result of the evaluated XPath expression is output**:

```
 Hello XML
   World!
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Should have taken a closer look at the xpath docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Nokogiri as an alternative for more XPath you can use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#inner_text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-inner_text):

```
puts doc.xpath('html/body/div/p[1]').inner_text
```